# Do I need Suntoolkit.realSync after SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()?

Tags: java, swing, invokeandwait

To be 100 % sure that the java application has refreshed everything on the screen do I need to call

`SunToolkit.realSync()`

after

`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` ?

I'm creating my GUI inside `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.

I would like to know if `invokeAndWait()` guarantees the refreshing same as `realSync()` guarantees.

Comment: not for why reason, but maybe depends of unstandard usage of Java Essential Classes with invokeAndWait(), note SunToolkit.realSync() doesn't refresh Swing GUI in the case that invokeAndWait() is called to EDT (generating a few awfull exception, more over it can caused exceptions from RepaintManager)

Comment: @mKorbel, sorry, I wasn't able to understand. I would like to know simply if invokeAndWait's postcondition includes that of realSync's